# How to use Apple's sfsymbol in Android

Tags: flutter

It's under development at Flutter

I want to use Apple's sf symbol on Android

There is an flutter_sfsymbols: ^2.0.0-in-flutter package, but the icon I want to use is not included in the flutter_sfsymbols: ^2.0.0-package

Do you have a way to use sf symbol in Android?